# Calculating Steering Angle for Curve

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I am a vehicle trying to get from point $A$ to point $B$. $A$ and $B$ are on the same line, but the vehicle needs to travel along a curve outside the line, how do I calculate what angle the vehicle needs be steering and where the vehicle should point to start off? Also, turning point needs to be halfway between point $A$ and $B$, and as close to $1$ meter off the line as possible. Is there a formula that takes into account mass and acceleration? 
[Diagram of what I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRby8.png)

Comment: The diagram makes no sense to me. What does make sense is finding the radius of the arc between the starting angle and the ending angle based and, based on the cord length, between the arc ends, setting a fixed rate of turn that matches the circle whose arc you are traversing.

Comment: Any answer is going to depend in a large part on the steering characteristics of the vehicle, its speed, &c, none of which you’ve provided.

Comment: Can you supply more details of this exercise?